# How to retrieve a name from another file with a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cut, parsing

I would like to grab a name out of another predefined file and use it within my shell script.

The file being read would be in `./docs/description.org`
and the format (a table in `.org` format) is:

```
...some text
| Time | 12.00      |
| Name | D0_50_H04  |
| blah | blah       |
... more text
```

The name is guaranteed to have no spaces (it will be alphanumeric + underscores), and it would be surrounded by the pipe `|` character, in the column directly following the only row containing the word "Name".

I would like to read the Name value (in this case "D0_50_H04") and use it within a shell script.

My Bash script looks something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

...some stuff

#Read in the model name
ModelName = #how do I do this??

#Create that directory
mkdir $SCRATCHDIR/$ModelName
cd $SCRATCHDIR/$ModelName

..continue working in that new dir
```

I was thinking of using grep, but I could not get it to work correctly.
Would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out: `awk '\Modelname\ {print}' directory/of/the/file`

Comment: awk was what I was looking for, indeed.  Here's the line in my Bash script that works for the example I gave above:  `modelName=\`awk '/Name/ {print $4}' ./docs/description.org\``

Comment: So, do you guarantee that the name will be surrounded ***by space characters***, separating the name from the vertical bars? If not, this won’t work correctly; it will include one or both vertical bars in the result. Try `ModelName=$(awk –F'|' '/Name/ {print $3}' docs/description.org)`.

Comment: @Scott in fact, the .org format does guarantee that there is a space character surrounding the name from vertical bars.

Comment: @Madeleine: That’s good to know. My point (which I guess I didn’t actually mention) is that clarifying information like that belongs in the question. You know that you can [edit] your question after posting it, right? (And by the way, this is not one of the rare cases where you need to use `./`.)

Answer (score 2):

What exactly does not work for you with [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)?
Try looking at [cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29) command. You are looking at something like:

> `grep YourFileNameHere -e "| Name |" | cut -d " "  -f 4`

this should parse `YourFileNameHere` and look for the line containing `| Name |` then pipe that line to the `cut` command that will pick the 4th token between  (space) delimiters, which according to your description should be `D0_50_H04`

Comment: Ah, it was the cut command that I didn't know about it. Thanks for the tip.